# Downscale an sql database hosted in Azure from Visual studio online

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I need to downscale a database in Azure to its Basic plan.

I have created a task in my Release flow on VSO, a PowerShell Azure Task with my subscription specified in it, and I've put this script in it :

```
Start-Sleep -s 60

$Credential = Get-Credential

$serverContext = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext -ServerName "XXX-com-staging" -Credential $Credential

$db = Get-AzureSqlDatabase -ServerName "XXX-com-staging" -DatabaseName "YYY-com-staging"

$P1 = Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServiceObjective $serverContext -ServiceObjectiveName "P1"

Set-AzureSqlDatabase $serverContext -Database $db -ServiceObjective $P1 -Force -Edition Basic
```

It doesn't work because $Credential is either Null, or it throws an Error saying that:

> Credential Parameter is mandatory.

Is there any simple way to achieve this, or a fix for my script ?

Comment: i think get-azuresqldatabase needs the context instead of the serverName-parameter

Comment: it has both overloads  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/get-azuresqldatabase?view=azuresmps-4.0.0

Comment: correctly. but i think the overload with the servername needs you to be logged in first. you created a context-object so i'd try to use the overload that accepts the context

Comment: ok, but how can I get the current context ?

Comment: you created the context in the third line.

Your forth line has to be $db = Get-AzureSqlDatabase -ConnectionContext $serverContext -DatabaseName "YYY-com-staging

Comment: the problem is that even Get-Credential nees a Credential Parameter : Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Credential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was easy, no need for Credentials

```
$P0 = Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServiceObjective -ServerName "XXX-com-staging" -ServiceObjectiveName "Basic"
Set-AzureSqlDatabase -DatabaseName "YYY-com-staging"  -ServerName "XXX-com-staging" -ServiceObjective $P0 -Force -Edition Basic
```